# My position: sticky is not working, any ideas?

Tags: html, css, css-position

I am creating a page with a side-nav that is displayed to the left of the main content.  I would like for this side-nav to remain in new (sticky) when the page scrolls, because the main content will be much larger than that of the side-nav.

I have checked for common issues that would prevent position: sticky from working, such as:

My content is not inside of a flex container, the top is defined, and there is no overflow set on any ancestor element.

My markup and styles are as follows:

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
}

.left {
  float: left;
  position: sticky;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  top: 0;
}

.right {
  margin-left: 15%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="left">
    <div>
      <div>Test 1</div>
      <div>Test 2</div>
      <div>Test 3</div>
      <div>Test 4</div>
      <div>Test 5</div>
      <div>Test 6</div>
      <div>Test 7</div>
      <div>Test 8</div>
      <div>Test 9</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="right">
    <div>
      This is really long content to test my sticky positioning! <br /> This is really long content to test my sticky positioning! <br /> This is really long content to test my sticky positioning! <br /> This is really long content to test my sticky positioning!
      <br /> This is really long content to test my sticky positioning! <br /> This is really long content to test my sticky positioning! <br /> This is really long content to test my sticky positioning! <br /> This is really long content to test my sticky
      positioning! <br /> This is really long content to test my sticky positioning! <br /> This is really long content to test my sticky positioning! <br /> This is really long content to test my sticky positioning! <br /> This is really long content
      to test my sticky positioning! <br /> This is really long content to test my sticky positioning! <br /> This is really long content to test my sticky positioning! <br /> This is really long content to test my sticky positioning! <br /> This is really
      long content to test my sticky positioning! <br /> This is really long content to test my sticky positioning! <br /> This is really long content to test my sticky positioning! <br /> This is really long content to test my sticky positioning! <br
      /> This is really long content to test my sticky positioning! <br /> This is really long content to test my sticky positioning! <br /> This is really long content to test my sticky positioning! <br /> This is really long content to test my sticky
      positioning! <br /> This is really long content to test my sticky positioning! <br /> This is really long content to test my sticky positioning! <br /> This is really long content to test my sticky positioning! <br /> This is really long content
      to test my sticky positioning! <br /> This is really long content to test my sticky positioning! <br /> This is really long content to test my sticky positioning! <br /> This is really long content to test my sticky positioning! <br /> This is really
      long content to test my sticky positioning! <br /> This is really long content to test my sticky positioning! <br /> This is really long content to test my sticky positioning! <br /> This is really long content to test my sticky positioning! <br
      /> This is really long content to test my sticky positioning! <br /> This is really long content to test my sticky positioning! <br /> This is really long content to test my sticky positioning! <br /> This is really long content to test my sticky
      positioning! <br /> This is really long content to test my sticky positioning! <br /> This is really long content to test my sticky positioning! <br /> This is really long content to test my sticky positioning! <br /> This is really long content
      to test my sticky positioning! <br /> This is really long content to test my sticky positioning! <br />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The issue is that the side-nav is not following the scroll of the page, and instead sticks at the top of the container.

Comment: your code is working fine

Comment: Dang, I thought I covered everything that could be causing the issue :(